# Can we change the spin of electron by applying electric field from ↑ to ↓ configuration?

Tags: quantum-spin, metals

I read in this forum a similary question with magnetic field. 
But is it possibile change the alignment of the spin with a electric field (DC or pulsant current) in a layer of metal?
Probably the metal must receive a crystallin surface (for example anodization)?
The change of alignment must be stable.
Thank you.

Comment: With a constant electric field it cannot be done. If the electric field is varying it will induce magnetic field from Maxwell equations and this will in turn can change the spin.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My question is: but the eletric filed must be applied DURING the formation of crystallin surface (anoditation) or AFTER the production of the crystallin surface? The change of alignment must be stable and on the metal changes with temperature. Thank you.